# How to perform inner join for this query

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelize.js

Can someone help me trouble shoot my syntax i spent 1 hour on it yet i cant figure it out.

I have 3 tables:

```
**Student**

-ID (UUID)

email (String)

**Teacher**

-ID (UUID)

email (String)

**StudentTeacher**

-ID (UUID)

studentId (UUID)

teacherId (UUID)
```

I have an initiate query which returns some studentId

```
SELECT studentId FROM TeacherStudents WHERE teacherId IN ('123', '456') GROUP BY studentId HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT teacherId) = 2
```

I would like to join the results with Students table so i can return the email address

However, this is not working

```
SELECT email FROM TeacherStudents WHERE teacherId IN ('123', '456') GROUP BY studentId HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT teacherId) = 2 INNER JOIN Students on TeacherStudents.studentId = Students.id
```

It returns an error.

Comment: Are you sure that this is MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
SELECT s.studentId, s.email
FROM TeacherStudents ts JOIN
     Students s
     ON ts.studentId = s.id
WHERE ts.teacherId IN (123, 456)
GROUP BY s.studentId, s.email
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ts.teacherId) = 2 ;
```

Notes:

- `WHERE` is a SQL clause that follows the `FROM` clause.
- `JOIN`s are an *operator* in the `FROM` clause.
- `TeacherId` is probably a number, so do not use single quotes.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- You are learning SQL, so be sure the unaggregated columns in `SELECT` match the `GROUP BY`.  You can drop `s.studentId` from the `SELECT` if you really want to.
- Qualify all column names so you know what table they come from.

Answer (score 1):

The generalised case, to get all columns from the Student table...

```
SELECT
  Students.*
FROM
(
  SELECT studentId
    FROM TeacherStudents
   WHERE teacherId IN ('123', '456')
GROUP BY studentId
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT teacherId) = 2
)
  StudentsOfInterest
INNER JOIN
  Students
    ON StudentsOfInterest.studentId = Students.id
```